# Event { "isTrusted": false } using Expo and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, react-native, xmlhttprequest, expo, form-data

I'm trying to upload(send) a PDF to server using below code snippet:

```
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/upload");
  xhr.onload = (e) => {
    const response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    console.log(response);
  };
  xhr.onerror = (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  };
  xhr.ontimeout = (e) => {
    console.log(e, "upload timeout");
  };
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("fileToUpload", {
    uri: fileToUpload.uri,
    type: `*/*`,
    name: fileToUpload.name,
  });

  xhr.send(formData);

  if (xhr.upload) {
    xhr.upload.onprogress = ({ total, loaded }) => {
      const uploadProgress = loaded / total;
      console.log(uploadProgress);
    };
  }
```

In response, I'm receiving following error:

```
Event {
  "isTrusted": false,
}
```

Any other approach to upload a file (pdf) to server using Expo, would also be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: To upload a file via FormData you have to pass the file itself to `formData.append`. Like `formData.append("fileToUpload", fileToUpload);`

Comment: doesn't get any luck. Still facing the same issue

Comment: @kartiktyagi could you finally solve it?

Comment: @4aLifeTime solution below is the correct workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, that the actual problem was- In android while selecting a file on Android device, DocumentPicker in Expo doesn't provide the complete path to the file, you have to manage it on your own, As I did below.

```
import * as DocumentPicker from "expo-document-picker";
...
const [singleFile, setSingleFile] = useState(null);

 const onSubmit = async () => {
      try {
        // upload the file
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("fileToUpload", singleFile);
        axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] =
          "multipart/form-data";
        const uploadResp = await axios.post(
          "/upload",
          formData
        );
        if (uploadResp.status === 200) {
          // file uploaded successfully
        } 
      } catch (error) {
      }
  };

  const selectFile = async () => {
    await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
      type: "application/pdf",
      copyToCacheDirectory: true,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.type == "success") {
          let { name, size, uri } = response;

          // >>>>>>>>>>>>> the bug's solution <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          if (Platform.OS === "android" && uri[0] === "/") {
            uri = `file://${uri}`;
            uri = uri.replace(/%/g, "%25");
          }

          let nameParts = name.split(".");
          let fileType = nameParts[nameParts.length - 1];
          setSingleFile({
            name: name,
            size: size,
            uri: uri,
            type: "application/" + fileType,
          });
        } else {
          setSingleFile(null);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };

...
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6} onPress={() => selectFile()}>
            <View >
              <Text >
                Select File
              </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @kartiktyagi. My situation is slightly different. I'm facing the issue using xmlHttpeRequest and Android to send stored base64 image locally - within SQLite - to Firestore. In case you re interested you can see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71722057/uploading-blob-with-xmlhttprequest-doesnt-work-in-android-react-native-expo)

Comment: I did the same way as you did on the first try, but it didn't work for me. So I solved it with the solution mentioned above.